# Python3 Whats wrong on simple code to reverse a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to reverse a list and although I found andiffernet way of doing it I still can't understand why the below doesn't work... Help, its driving my mad!

```
a=list("effort") 
k=len(a)
l=a
for i in range (k):
    l[i] = a[k-1]
    print(i)
    k=k-1
print(l)
```

Comment: You overwrite the first half of the list with the contents of the second half. Suppose you start with the list `[1, 2]`. After the first iteration, you have `[2, 2]`. There's no longer a `1` left in the list to copy to the second slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
l = a
```

The thing that's tripping you up here is that the variable `a` is a reference to a list object.  When you say `l = a` you're essentially saying, "Make `l` refer to the exact same list that `a` refers to".  So when you make a change to `l` you are ALSO making a change to `a` because they're the same thing.

It will work if you change the line to this:

```
l = list(a)
```

This says "make a new list object that is a copy of `a` and point `l` at that new list."  Now when you make changes to `l` you don't affect `a`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `l=a', you are assigning a reference to the original list, so your operations are executed on the original list. Try 'l = [c for c in a]' or 'l = list(a)' instead, so that you operate on a copy of the original list.